# Finding a function with Fourier expansion

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I have to find the function for a sawtooth wave form, and using that the line has these conditions:

$$
f(x)=
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & 0\leq x \leq 1 \\
    x-0.5 & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
    x -1 & 2 \leq x \leq 3 \\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
After $x=3$ the function just repeats itself.
I compute the integrals for the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ and get the following for the full Fourier expansion.
$$F(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(0.5n\sin(2n)+0.5n\sin(n)+2n\sin(3n)+\cos(3n)-1)\cos(nx)+(\sin(3n)-0.5n\cos(2n)-0.5n\cos(n)-2n\cos(3n))\sin(nx)}{n^2}$$

when I plot this I get the following function:
[image]

Why doesn't the function repeat after $x=3$? My function also seems quite complicated, is it possible theres a simpler method?

Comment: Yes, thank you, just corrected it

Comment: Note that your function repeats after $x=2\pi$. That's because you're using functions which are $2\pi$-periodic, e.g., $\cos(x)$. You need to use functions which are $3$-periodic instead.

Comment: Thank you, I realised I was using different periods for every piece of the function. Instead of using cos(nx) I used cos(2πnx/3) which solved my problem.

Comment: If you've figured it out, I encourage you to post your corrected solution as an answer to your own question. That'll give you a chance to build rep and to get feedback on your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem with the help of 'Semiclassical' in the comments and I get the correct periodic function now when I plot it. My mistake was using a $2\pi$ periodic function instead of a $3$-periodic function. To solve this I only had to add $2\pi$ to the sine and cosine in the Fourier expansion. The correct form of the series for my case was:

$$
f(x)=C+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left( a_{n}\cos \frac{2{\pi}nx}{T}+b_{n}\sin \frac{2{\pi}nx}{T}\right), \tag{1}
$$

and the Integrals for the coefficients had the same change to the cosine and sine:
$$
a_{n} =\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)\cos \left(\frac{2{\pi}nx}{T}\right)
$$

the same applies to $b_{n}$ and $a_{0}$.